# Argument passing into IIFE

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, ecmascript-5

Do anyone can explain and prove which one of examples is "more correct"?

A: pass object as an argument

```
(function($){
    $.doStuff();
})(jQuery);
```

B: retrieve object within the function

```
(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;
    $.doStuff();
})();
```

I really like B because of its readability. Only technical difference between A and B is that B has to lookup one more scope. I consider this as marginal difference so why is "recomended" the A way?

Note that the jQuery is just example. Important is the nature of the problem: Pass as argument or retrieve within the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equivalent, but I like the first example (passing as an argument) more as it saves you one line of code. That also means that your function does not contain unnecessary logic.

Answer (score 2):

The second way will *only* work if the name of the jQuery library is really "jQuery". It's possible (though unusual) to call `.noConflict()` like this:

```
window.banana = jQuery.noConflict( true );
```

Then, your first example would still work:

```
(function($) {
  $.doStuff();
})( banana );
```

but your second example would fail (as written). Of course, you could similarly hard-code the name "banana" into the second one too, but if that function isn't directly under your control, you can't; plus it's a "DRY" violation.

Imagine that you've got an initialization function being loaded in a separate JavaScript source file; perhaps it's a 3rd-party script.  If you want to call that function at initialization time, you'll have more flexibility if the function takes the jQuery reference as a parameter instead of just making the assumption that the global symbol is anything in particular.

```
alienInitializationFunction( banana );
```

will still work, in other words.

Comment: I assume that if I have the argument under my controll then I have even the function body under my control. The (...)(foo); is an inseparable part of (function(bar){...})(...);, isn't it correct? Whats the diference of changing (jQuery) -> (banana) and var $ = jQuery; -> var $ = banana; ?

Comment: @svobol13 I will extend the answer with an example.

Comment: @svobol13 answer extended. The basic notion is that it's good practice to avoid coupling code inside functions to external symbols that the function cannot control. It's not that it won't work, it's that it's a "code smell" and can be a source of bugs later.

Comment: But this is not regular function. I understand IIFE that its just block of code that has its own fresh context. It cannot be called (because it has no name) it cannot be passed anywhere its just declared where it is and there called. Theres only two possible places where you can place jQuery (its just an example, lets say its a foo). Inside (foo) or after = foo; Both places are 'hardcoded' and 'tightly-coupled' to the 'function' declaration :(

Comment: @svobol13 well ultimately it's just a matter of opinion and coding style.